# OWLReasonerRuntimeException in Protégé using Geonames ontology

Tags: resources, external, protege, geonames

I built an ontology in Protégé 4 to describe archaeological finds and I'd like to use Geonames individuals as places of discovery.  How can I add external individuals in Protégé?  Do I need to import the Geonames ontology in mine? I tried to:

1. import geonames ontology
2. add new individual with geonames full iri
3. add property sameAs between my place and the new individual of the point 2

but importing the Geonames ontology makes the reasoner to die with this error message:

> OWLReasonerRuntimeException: Non-simple object property 'http://www.geonames.org/ontology#featureClass' is used as a simple one

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Using individuals from other ontologies without importing them

In general, it's probably a good idea to import the ontologies that declare the individuals that you're interested in using.  However,in some cases, this might not be the best option.  As described in the following sections, the Geonames ontology is not actually a legal OWL 2 DL ontology, so if you try to import it into your ontology, you'll run into issues when you try to do any reasoning.  As such, you should *not* import the Geonames ontology into yours, and you *should* redeclare the individuals that you want in your own ontology.  This is easy in Protégé.  According to the [GeoNames ontology page](http://www.geonames.org/ontology/documentation.html#featureClass), the IRI `http://sws.geonames.org/3020251/` refers to town called Embrun in France.  You simply create an individual in the usual way that you would with Protégé, but check the "ignore entity creation preferences" button so that you can enter a full IRI for the individual:

[image]

[image]

### Concerning Simple Properties

There are restrictions on how certain OWL properties can be used.  If you're getting an error about

> OWLReasonerRuntimeException: Non-simple object property
>   'http://www.geonames.org/ontology#featureClass' is used as a simple
>   one

then you're referencing the property correctly.  In the [OWL 2 Web Ontology Language 
Structural Specification and Functional-Style Syntax (Second Edition)](http://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-syntax/) there's a description of simple properties (but I'm only including an excerpt here):

> #### [11.1 Property Hierarchy and Simple Object Property Expressions](http://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-syntax/#Property_Hierarchy_and_Simple_Object_Property_Expressions)
>
> Roughly speaking, a simple object property expression has no direct or
>   indirect subproperties that are either transitive or are defined by
>   means of property chains, where the notion of indirect subproperties
>   is captured by the property hierarchy.

There are restictions on how simple and non-simple properties can be used:

> #### [11.2 The Restrictions on the Axiom Closure](http://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-syntax/#The_Restrictions_on_the_Axiom_Closure)
>
> Restriction on Simple Roles. Each class expression and each axiom in
>   Ax of type from the following two lists contains only simple object
>   properties.
>
> - ObjectMinCardinality, ObjectMaxCardinality, ObjectExactCardinality, and ObjectHasSelf .
> - FunctionalObjectProperty, InverseFunctionalObjectProperty, IrreflexiveObjectProperty, AsymmetricObjectProperty, and
>     DisjointObjectProperties.
>
> This restriction is necessary in order to guarantee decidability of
>   the basic reasoning problems for OWL 2 DL.

### Geonames is not an OWL 2 DL ontology

Now, it could be that your ontology has some problematic axioms, but it looks like there are some in the GeoNames ontology itself. I downloaded [version 3.1](http://www.geonames.org/ontology/ontology_v3.1.rdf) and opened it up in Protégé.  There aren't all that many object properties, but there's one, *feature class*, that has a subproperty chain axiom, and it's used in a class expression.

[image]

So, *feature class* is a non-simple property because it has a property chain as a subproperty, and *feature class* is used in an ObjectExactCardinality class expression, namely,

> *feature class* **exactly** 1 *Thing*

This means that the GeoNames ontology is not a legal OWL 2 DL ontology.

Comment: @user3184870 You piqued my curiosity, so I downloaded the geonames ontology and pulled it up in Protégé.  It violates the constraints on OWL 2 DL ontologies, so it's not a legal OWL 2 DL ontology.  I've updated my answer to explain why.  It might be worthwhile sending a note to their mailing list or similar contact to check whether this was their intent.