# Pellet transitivity protege 5 classifiers

Tags: owl, ontology, protege, pellet

I'm using Protege beta 5 and I'm trying to use a reasoner .
Since pellet doesnt support transitivity between individuals What is the solution for that problem if there is any ?
If not Are there any reasoners  That support (Equivalence,transitivty , reflexivity ...)
getting inconsistent ontology and thats the explaination is    :

```
 A(b) -> ((isComposedOf min 2 ({C})) and (isComposed max 15 ({C})))(b)
  b Type A
  ((isComposed exactly 4 AA) or (isComposed exactly 5 AA)) (?x),L(?x),((hasLength exactly 4 xsd:integer) or (hasLength exactly 5 xsd:integer))(?x)-?SameAs(?x,R)
```

Comment: In which way is it not supported? Which DL expressivity includes these constructs for individuals?

Comment: Using OWL , for more semantic I'm trying to use a reasoner for consistency , Although with  pellet  I'm getting an error cause of transitive property Key words TYPE ans SAME AS Thats the problem , ANd seems like pellet isnt supporting those properties @Ignazio

Comment: Pellet supports full OWL 2 DL! Please post the error, i.e. the full stacktrace. The only exception with transitive properties is a warning that the transitivity of a property will be ignored to avoid the violation of the OWL 2 DL restrictions.

Comment: @AKSW I edited the post . I'm a newbie in the domain so .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pellet supports transitive properties.  I believe you stumbled upon non simple properties used in simple property positions. This is not Pellet's limitation, it's a DL limitation - some combinations of characteristics are not supported, because they lead to undecidability. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21135179/owlreasonerruntimeexception-in-prot%C3%A9g%C3%A9-using-geonames-ontology) for relevant information

Comment: Thank You Im gonna check it out

Comment: Does it support the Type and SameAs key words?

Comment: Yes, it does - these are supported by any OWL 2 reasoner.